# What's wrong with this part of ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a series and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}>1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

**Attempt:** Suppose  $r= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|},r>1$. Then  there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies |\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} -r|<r-1=\epsilon$. Thus, $n \geq N \implies \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}>1$. Thus $n \geq N \implies |a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$. So that $\sum a_n$ diverges by the $n'th$ term test.

Comment:According to my professor, there are minor issues with this proof?Can anyone explain where the fault is?

Comment: What if $r=\infty$?

Comment: Sorry, $r$ is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved correctly that $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$ (if $n\gg1$). In order to apply the $n$<sup>th</sup> term test, you should now say that a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative numbers cannot have limit equal to $0$ (and perhaps that you could justify why). So, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$, and this is the same thing as asserting that you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. And *now* the $n$<sup>th</sup> term test says that the series diverges.